# How to send PDF file to client using servlet.?

Tags: java, web-services, pdf, file-upload

I'm trying a small code to send PDF file to client using servlet. I've developed one code which is attahed below. When I run this code in NetBeans on glassfish server, one pop download window appears and I click on open option It's says "There is problem with format" and I'm not able to see content from file.
So can anyone help me to solve this logical error ?

```
  package com.transferPDF;

  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileInputStream;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.OutputStream;
  import java.io.PrintWriter;
  import javax.servlet.ServletException;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

  public class PDFserver extends HttpServlet {


protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    int BUFF_SIZE = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFF_SIZE];
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=E:/test.pdf");
    File filePDF=new File("E:/test.pdf");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePDF);
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
       response.setContentLength((int) filePDF.length());
        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

        try {
            int byteRead = 0;
            while ((byteRead = fis.read()) != -1) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, byteRead);

            }
            os.flush();
            } catch (Exception excp) {
            excp.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            os.close();
            fis.close();
        }
    }
}


@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
 *
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}


@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
  }

}
```

Comment: Instead of opening it, can you save it somewhere and examine it?

Comment: Yes, I did so. But happens same @DavidT.Macknet

Comment: Same things happens when you try to open the saved version?  And you've verified you can open it prior to sending it through this code - that it wasn't corrupted when it was saved, rather than being corrupted on output?

Comment: Yes. I've created test.PDF by myself and it's not corrupted in any case.@DavidT.Macknet

Answer (score 0):

Use following for header

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"test.pdf\"");
```

Comment: And/or add `ContentType = "application/pdf"`

Answer (score 0):

You just needed to make a few changes to the way you're writing out the PDF.

I got the code here to return a PDF that rendered correctly Chrome.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        int BUFF_SIZE = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFF_SIZE];
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        File filePDF = new File("c:\\my.pdf");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePDF);     
        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        try
        {
            response.setContentLength((int) filePDF.length());
            int byteRead = 0;
            while ((byteRead = fis.read()) != -1)
            {
                os.write(byteRead);
            }
            os.flush();
        }
        catch (Exception excp)
        {
            excp.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            os.close();
            fis.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you replace the path to the PDF with the correct path on your system? Also, what do you mean it's not working? I've used that code to download  PDF.

Comment: Not working means that I've applied your code snippet but I'm seeing same output. What do you mean by replacement of correct path.? @AdamRice

Comment: @NirmalPurohit if you did a straight copy/paste of my code it won't work. Unless you happen to have C:\my.pdf on your system.

Comment: i know coding standards and how to use suggested code in my program. I replaced file path of yours to mine